# Seleccionar y luego Insertar

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Necesito hacer un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL:

Tengo un **select** en donde rescato datos:

```
 select columna1, columna1, columna1, columna1, columna1 from TB1
```

y estos datos tomados necesito pasarlos a una tabla nueva (**TB2**):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Talves es tan simple como lo pienso (pero no he probado):

```
 INSERT INTO TB2 (columna1,columna2,columna3,columna4,columna5) VALUES (TB1.columna1,TB1.columna2,TB1.columna3,TB1.columna4,TB1.columna5)
```

***No quiero setiar cada columna en una variable, debido a que el dato unico se puede duplicar y me arrojara error de "subquery retorna mas de 1 valor"***

DESARROLLADO:

```
  CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
  PROCEDURE SELECCIONAR_INSERTAR
  BEGIN

  DECLARE NEW_COL1 VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE NEW_COL2 VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE NEW_COL3 VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE NEW_COL4 VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE NEW_COL5 VARCHAR(10);



SELECT NEW_COL1=COLUMNA1,
       NEW_COL2=COLUMNA2,
       NEW_COL3=COLUMNA3,
       NEW_COL4=COLUMNA4,
       NEW_COL5=COLUMNA5
FROM   TB1;





INSERT INTO TB2 (COLUMNA1,
                 COLUMNA2,
                 COLUMNA3,
                 COLUMNA4,
                 COLUMNA5) VALUES (NEW_COL1,
                                   NEW_COL2,
                                   NEW_COL3,
                                   NEW_COL4,
                                   NEW_COL5);

  END
```

Esto no llena nada, hay que tomar en cuenta que el **select** de la **TB1** trae miles de datos....

Comment: No recuerdo si en mysql se puede pero podrías intentar un insert select,
INSERT INTO table-name (column-names)
SELECT column-names 
 FROM table-name
WHERE condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto tienes una clausula de [`INSERT INTO... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) que te permite insertar directamente el resultado de una consulta. Obviamente tienen que coincidir cantidad, tipos y longitudes de columnas entre la consulta y la tabla dónde vas a insertar.

En tu caso, la sintaxis sería algo así:

```
INSERT INTO TB2 (COLUMNA1,
                 COLUMNA2,
                 COLUMNA3,
                 COLUMNA4,
                 COLUMNA5)
SELECT COLUMNA1,
       COLUMNA2,
       COLUMNA3,
       COLUMNA4,
       COLUMNA5
FROM   TB1;
```

Comment: lo pruebo de inmediato y te cuento.

Comment: Es lo que necesitaba!! Muchas Gracias @Patricio